# Can I run core 3.1 subsite application under .netframework application

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, application-pool

I m working for run a .net core app under a .net framework app. When I tried to run core under core its working but not working I wanted way. Application pools are seperate and the option inheritInChildApplications 
on webconfig is false. Example usage:  example.com/ => .net framework and  example.com/api => .net core

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to nested the asp.net core application into the asp.net application, I suggest you could add nested application inside the IIS website.

To achieve this, you could refer to below steps:

1.Open the IIS management console,right click the application and select the add application.

[image]

2.Then select the asp.net core folder and create the application as API

[image]

3.Add ignore route in the parent asp.net application.

Comment: I have tried this vay but https://prnt.sc/s0cyy9 the state is same.